# rails using link_to with namespaced routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've created a set of routes & controllers with the admin namespace, and I was having some issues using the link helpers with these new routes.

I see that there are some new path helpers, such as admin_projects_path which leads to the /admin/projects.  however, i'm having trouble linking to the show, edit, destroy, etc. paths for these objects within the namespace. how do I do that?

Comment: I came here to ask this exact question for this exact use case. +1  (I see that a better answer has shown itself over time)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You should see all of your routes listed in `rake routes` and you can use those by name to get the proper namespacing. Using the automatic detection where you pass in `:controller` and `:action` manually won't work as you've discovered.

If it's listed as `new_thing` in the routes, then the method is `new_thing_path` with the appropriate parameters. For instance:

```
link_to('New Project', new_admin_project_path)
link_to('Projects', admin_projects_path)
link_to(@project.name, admin_project_path(@project))
link_to(@project.name, edit_admin_project_path(@project))
link_to(@project.name, admin_project_path(@project), :method => :delete)
```

Answer (score 79):

If you're using **Rails 3**, you can use your admin namespace with the variable instead of writing the long helper path name.

view:

```
<td><%= link_to 'Show', [:admin, project] %></td>
<td><%= link_to 'Edit', [:edit, :admin, project] %></td>
<td><%= link_to 'Destroy', [:admin, project], confirm: 'Are you sure?', method: :delete %></td>
```

controller:

```
redirect_to [:admin, @project]
```

Comment: For the edit action, I had to do `<%= link_to 'Edit', [:admin, :edit, project] %>` for some reason.

Comment: +1 for the answer, and I think this should be updated as the accepted answer and its more accurate

Comment: @pinouchon I know it seems weird, but the edit part (action) needs to be first (before the namespace) because the helper method reads `edit_admin_city_path` rather than `admin_edit_city_path`. It seems that the namespace should be first.

Comment: How about the `projects/new` path? I tried `[:new, :admin, Project]`, but it does not work.

Comment: Hi Andrei, you need to do [:new, :admin, :project]. You can't pass a project instance because you are creating a new one so passing a symbol works here.

Comment: How I use uuid in place of id in urls?

Comment: @LalitKumar I think that would be set in your Model. These helpers use whatever primary key is implemented.

Answer (score 1):

Some methods require a :url option as a parameter, and in those cases you can use url_for to generate the path:

```
icon(:url => url_for(:controller => "admin/projects", :action => "edit", :id => @project),
     :type => :edit)
```

Comment: Rails gives us an automatic helper for the URL path with `edit_admin_project_url`.