# How to route actions based on object class with namespaced controllers in Rails 5.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, namespaces

I am refactoring my application so that users are now managed in a dedicated Administration namespace. I did the following:

**routes.rb**

```
  namespace :administration do
    get 'users',           to: "/administration/users#index"
    resources :users
    resources :groups
  end
```

The **Users** and **Groups** controller are now in the app/controllers/administration folder. They are defined as **Administration::UsersController** and **Administration::GroupsController**. The models are not namespaced.

The related links are now based on **administration_users_path** and **administration_groups_path**.

I use some partials for hamonised layout. One of them diplays **Edit** and **Delete** buttons, where *this_object* represents the instance passed to the locals:

**_object_actions.erb**

```
<% if this_object.is_active %>

  <%= link_to [ :edit, this_object], method: :get, class: "mat-flat-button mat-button-base mat-primary" do%>
    <span class="fa fa-edit"></span>
    <%= t("Edit") %>
  <% end %>

  <%= link_to this_object, data: { confirm: t("Sure") }, method: :delete, class: "mat-flat-button mat-button-base mat-warn" do%>
    <span class="fa fa-trash"></span>
    <%= t("Destroy") %>
  <% end %>

<% else %>

  <%= link_to [ :activate, this_object], method: :post, class: "mat-stroked-button mat-button-base" do%>
    <span class="fa fa-trash-restore"></span>
    <%= t("Recall") %>
  <% end %>

<% end %>
```

But coming to to Users and Groups, the path to actions is not properly built. I would need to build the URL such as **/administration/users/1/edit**, but it actually is **/users/1/edit**.

How can I make sure to build the correct URL for this purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to this post [Rails using link to with namespaced routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269884/rails-using-link-to-with-namespaced-routes/9068650), I undestood that it is possible to add more parameters to the link_to method to build the actual link.

To call namespaced controller methods, I added the following to the links:

```
<%# Check if the parent is a module defined as Namespace. If not (Object) then display default link %>
<% namespace = controller.class.parent.name == 'Object' ? 
   nil : 
   controller.class.parent.name.downcase %>

<% if this_object.is_active %>
  <%= link_to [ :edit, namespace, this_object], 
      method: :get, 
      class: "mat-flat-button mat-button-base mat-primary" do %>
      <span class="fa fa-edit"></span>
      <%= t("Edit") %>
  <% end %>

  <%= link_to [namespace, this_object], 
      data: { confirm: t("Sure") }, 
      method: :delete, 
      class: "mat-flat-button mat-button-base mat-warn" do %>
      <span class="fa fa-trash"></span>
      <%= t("Destroy") %>
  <% end %>

<% else %>

  <%= link_to [ :activate,  namespace, this_object], 
      method: :post, 
      class: "mat-stroked-button mat-button-base" do %>
      <span class="fa fa-trash-restore"></span>
      <%= t("Recall") %>
  <% end %>

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the desired route for each `link_to`

```
<%= link_to "Edit", edit_administration_user_path(this_object) %>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, using a partial I address various models and controllers, so I can't hardcode the path method.